# Como lidar com dependências (DLL's) em Delphi/Lazarus?

Tags: delphi, dll, lazarus, dependências

- Como é que eu faço para descobrir quais *DLL's* eu devo distribuir junto com a minha aplicação para que ela funcione em qualquer máquina?
- Eu conheço o InstallShield - que faz o negócio de maneira automatizada - mas eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira gratuita de fazer isso, ainda que manual?
- E outra pergunta ainda: é sufiente incluir as *DLL's* na mesma pasta do executável da minha aplicação ou há *DLL's* que precisam ser incluídas em outras pastas (como a **System32**, por exemplo)?

Comment: Que negócio que o InstallShield faz de maneira automatizada?

Comment: @EMBarbosa, ele analisa a sua aplicação, mapeia as _DLL's_ que ela acessa (pra isso ele pede pra tu rodar a aplicação e "navegar" por ela) e então gera o instalador já com as _DLL's_ incluídas. No caso, se fosse para fazer sem ele, eu não saberia quais _DLL's_ incluir, de onde encontrá-las e se distribuí-las na mesma pasta do `.exe` é suficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O normal é que você saiba de quais dlls o seu software depende. Não faz sentido o seu software depender de uma dll e você, como programador não saber disso.

Algumas opções no entanto são:

1. No Delphi ,durante o debug do seu programa, você pode usar a tela do
   menu View -> Debug Windows -> Modules. Ela mostra todos as dlls
   carregadas.
2. Conforme mencionado na [resposta pelo DBX8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13108/2652) você pode usar o [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
3. No prompt de comando (`cmd`) use o comando `tasklist /m`. Ele fará uma lista de todas as dlls utilizadas por cada programa específico sendo executado.

Uma pergunta relacionada no SO é esta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475148/how-do-i-find-out-which-dlls-an-executable-will-load

Comment: O problema é o seguinte: abri um projeto aqui e esta tela indicou uns 30 DLL's diferentes. Porém o InstallShield indicou apenas uma DLL para incluir. Ou seja: esta lista de DLL's não está filtrada, ela inclui DLL's que são do próprio Windows.

Comment: @user3153542 Você disse que serviria algo que fosse manual. Qualquer uma das opções são manuais. Estou adicionando outras ferramentas a lista, mas fora processos manuais, não sei exatamente o que você poderia fazer.

Comment: OK, acho que fiquei mal acostumado com o InstallShield, achei que poderia existir algo semelhante mas gratuito. O jeito é se virar com oque tem. :)

Comment: @user3153542 talvez até exista, mas eu desconheço. O fato é que "em todos esses anos nessa indústria vital" eu nunca precisei de procurar por uma dll no meu software que eu não tenha adicionado propositalmente. Para software de "terceiros" eu já usei o PEExplorer, Filemon, SoftIce, etc... mas aí o trabalho era sempre manual mesmo. :)

Comment: O InstallShield retornou apenas uma DLL porque as outras são padrão do Windows ou você o configurou para obter dos seus pacotes originais, que muitas vezes estão disponíveis em links padrão no site do fabricante (muito comum com as MSVCRT, distribuídas pela Microsoft). Pode ser até que alterando as configurações do Installshield, você obtenha resultados diferentes (como mais ou menos DLL's).

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira acho que seu comentário deveria ser direcionado ao originador da pergunta. (:

Answer (score 3):

> Como é que eu faço para descobrir quais DLL's eu devo distribuir junto
> com a minha aplicação para que ela funcione em qualquer máquina?
>
> Eu conheço o InstallShield - que faz o negócio de maneira automatizada, mas eu gostaria de
> saber se existe alguma maneira gratuita de fazer isso, ainda que manual?

O [**Dependency Walker**](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) parece ser um bom utilitário para isso.

Algumas características:

- Gratuito
- Disponível para Windows *95, 98, Me, NT, 2000, XP, 2003, Vista, 7* e *8*
- Ele pode processar qualquer módulo do Windows *32* bits ou *64* bits, incluindo os desenvolvidos para o *Windows CE*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> É suficiente incluir as DLL's na mesma pasta do
> executável da minha aplicação ou há DLL's que precisam ser incluídas
> em outras pastas (como a System32, por exemplo)?

Isso dependerá bastante do objetivo da sua aplicação, mas o ideal é colocar as *DLLs* na mesma pasta do executável, utilizar outras pastas como a *System32* provavelmente vai criar um impasse com as permissões de usuário([**UAC**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)). Um bom lugar para armazenar os dados do aplicativo é na pasta [**AppData**](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-8/what-appdata-folder).

Como [mencionado pelo EMBarbosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12871/como-lidar-com-depend%C3%AAncias-dlls-em-delphi-lazarus/13108#comment23135_13108), evitar o uso da pasta *System32* também pode lhe poupar de problemas como o [DLL Hell](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_de_DLLs).